# How to use PDO::quote to escape a string in a LIKE expression?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I try to use `PDO::quote` to escape a string in a `LIKE` expression, so the user string must not be surrounded like in :

```
LIKE "%userStringToEscape%"
```

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Why not just take the `"` out of the statement? And let `%userStringToEscape%` "own" the quote marks?

Comment: % will be escape by the function i think - That's a bit dirty to remove quote like this :)

Comment: % doesn't get escaped by quote. `quote()` only escapes SQL injections, not LIKE queries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$var = "%userStringToEscape%";
$var = $pdo->quote($var);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE $var";
```

but instead of using quote() you should be really using prepared statements

```
$var = "%userStringToEscape%";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE $var");
$stmt->execute($var);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: The answer to the question is "you cannot do this (and there doesn't appear to be a need to -- see Shrapnel's answer -- unless you're concatenating multiple 'escaped' inputs into one string)" :)

Comment: Ok and is there a function that escape % and _ for `LIKE` statement ? different from quote then ?

Comment: I'm guessing `str_replace` will do that

Answer (score 4):

The clean solution to do this is, of course, `$db->quote('%'.$var.'%')`

Answer (score -1):

Just do:

```
$like = $pdo->quote("%{$userStringToEscape}%");
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM field LIKE {$like}";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php